# Tkinter optionmenu add_command strings do not show on widget when selected

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

```
from tkinter import *


main = Tk()

var = StringVar()
options = OptionMenu(main, var, 'option1')
options.grid()
options['menu'].add_command(label='option2')


main.mainloop()
```

When you select 'option1' in the menu it shows that string on the widget. If you select 'option2' it does not show that string on the widget. If you set a command for option2 it will run. Why is 'option2' not showing in the widget when it is selected?

python 3.5

UPDATE:

By adding strings through a for loop I run into a problem where the command for each string uses the same variable.

```
from tkinter import *

def _print(var, string):
    print(string)
    var.set(string)

lst = ['hello', 'bob', 'testing']

main = Tk()
var = StringVar()
options = OptionMenu(main, var, 'option1')
options.grid()

for string in lst:
    options['menu'].add_command(label=string, command=lambda: _print(var, string))

main.mainloop()
```

I tried using `lambda event, i=string: _print(var, i))` in the loop but lamdba doesnt like it. Says its missing 'event'. I've put event in the _print function and the call to _print but I get the same error that lamdba is missing event. Any idea how I can pass the right variable for each command in the loop?

Comment: Please include the generic [tag:python] tag unless the question is exclusively about version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when you declared 'option2' in the `Optionmenu()` widget. More examples can be read from [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) and [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/optionmenu.html).

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

var = StringVar()
options = OptionMenu(main, var, 'option1', 'option2')
options.grid()
#options['menu'].add_command(label='option2')


main.mainloop()
```

I found that the `menu` option is used for creating items in a `Menu()` widget but not for a `Optionmenu()` widget. This is stated [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/menu-toplevel.html).  You can read more about how to declare a `.Menu()` widget [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/menu-toplevel.html). All the best to your tkinter developments.

**Edit1:**

The reason why it was failing was because you did not declare the `command` option associated with the `.add_command` method. Having done this alone, you will notice that the `Optionmenu` still does not get updated with the new label of the added menu item. To resolve this issue, you have to use the `.set()` method of the Control Variable `StringVar` to do the updating. See revised script below.

```
from tkinter import *

def _print1(value):
    # By default, callback to OptionMenu has a positional argument for the 
    #  menu item's label. 
    print(value)
    print(var.get())
    
def _print2():
    var.set('option2')
    print(var.get())

main = Tk()

var = StringVar()
options = OptionMenu(main, var, 'option1',command=_print1)
options.grid()
options['menu'].add_command(label='option2', command=_print2)
# To add more clickable menu items, the 'add_command' method requires you to
# to declare it's options 'label' and 'command'.

main.mainloop()
```

**Edit2:**

1. Remark, I have added the `command` aspect to `options` in **Edit1**. I
   did not address earlier but thought it needed to be shown for
   completeness.
2. Responding to your question in your UPDATE, to do what you want, I
   rewrote the script as a class object. Also I used the internal class
   `_setit` found in tkinter, which the `OptionMenu` widget had used to
   do configure the callback used by `command`. This approach overcame the issue you encountered.

**Revised Code:**

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.createOM()
        self.grid()

    def createOM(self):
        # Create OptionMenu
        omlist=['option1']
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.options = OptionMenu(self, self.var, *omlist,
                                  command=self._print1)
        self.options.grid()
        
        values = ['hello', 'bob', 'testing']
        for v in values:
            self.options['menu'].add_command(
                label=v, command=_setit(self.var, v, self._print2))
        # To add more clickable menu items, the 'add_command' method requires you to
        # to declare it's options 'label' and 'command'.
       
    def _print1(self, value, *args):
        #callback for OptionMenu has these arguments because inherently it
        #uses the _setit class to configure the callback with these arguments. 
        print()        
        print(value)        
        #self.var.set('option10') #Uncomment to change OptionMenu display
        print(self.var.get())

    def _print2(self, value, *args):
        print()        
        print(value)        
        #self.var.set('option20') #Uncomment to change OptionMenu display
        print(self.var.get())
   
#The following class is extracted from tkinter.
class _setit:
    """Internal class. It wraps the command in the widget OptionMenu."""
    def __init__(self, var, value, callback=None):
        self.__value = value
        self.__var = var
        self.__callback = callback
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.__var.set(self.__value)
        if self.__callback:
            self.__callback(self.__value, *args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I appreciate the info but I already know that it works if I include it in the optionmenu when its created instead of adding it later. My question was 
 about why its failing when adding it later.

Comment: @sidnical I have appended an answer in reply to your question. Best Wishes.

Comment: @sidnical I just saw @Nae have replied you 10hrs ago but that answer is incorrect. What you are doing is not a hack. Your approach is permissible/sound because `OptionMenu` is an inheritance of `Menu`. Your issue arose because you forgot to provide the `command` option required in the `add_command` method.

Comment: So you're saying its required that a command be set for each option item that manually sets the widget to that string? I guess this is what the default configuration is doing when you create the widget.

Comment: Yes. Can confirm the revised script works on your system? If it works, kindly deselect the other answer and select this answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Seems to work when adding strings to the menu one by one. Im adding the strings to the option menu with a for loop(updated in question) and it only carries the last variable used for all commands. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @sidnical I have provided a workaround but it involves expressing the previous code as a class object.

Comment: @sidnical I previously commented that `OptionMenu` is an inheritance of `Menu`. This is incorrect. It actually inherits it attribute from `Menubutton` which inherits from the `Widget` class. But since Tk8.0, `Menubutton` has became obsolete. So presently, `OptionMenu` really inherits its attributes from the `Widget` class in tkinter.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Im looking more into ways keep the string unique for each line. You've answered my original question. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't select anything because *it's not supposed to*. You're basically hacking `OptionMenu`'s visual part. The items you pass as `values` are first added to the menu and then are given the command option to modify the selection. When you call `options['menu'].add_command(label='option2')` you're basically only modifying the visual part of the widget, `'option2'` is *not* added to values, and thus command option *isn't* set. See for yourself in the source code [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/102005894/).

Comment: So theirs no way of adding/modifying the optionmenu content? Suprising how many pages say to use add_command, insert, and .entryconfig(for older versions I think) to do this type of thing. Guess i'll just destroy the object and recreate it with an updated list of values. Thank you.

Comment: @sidnical You can modify its content with some workarounds but I think it is too much effort. It surprises me as well how OptionMenu works. Perhaps see [tag:ttk].[Combobox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Combobox.html).